# Laravel & Ajax send HTML form with errors

Tags: laravel

Here is an action:

```
   public function postMessageAjax(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'required|string|regex:/^[a-zA-Z\d]+$/',
        'email' => 'required|string|email',
        'homepage' => 'nullable|string|url',
        'text' => 'string',
        'captcha' => 'required|captcha',
    ],
        [
            'captcha.captcha' => 'The captcha is incorrect',
            'username.regex' => 'Use English letters and digits only',
        ]);

    $message = new Message();

    $message->username = $request->get('username');

    $message->email = $request->get('email');

    $message->homepage = $request->get('homepage');

    $message->text = strip_tags($request->get('text'));

    $message->ip = $request->ip();

    $message->browser = get_browser($request->header('User-Agent'))->browser;

    $message->save();

    return view('Guestbook.postMessage');
}
```

And here is the view:

```
{!! BootForm::open(['id' => 'messageForm']) !!}
{!! BootForm::text('username') !!}

{!! BootForm::email('email') !!}

{!! BootForm::text('homepage') !!}

{!! BootForm::textarea('text') !!}

{!! captcha_img('flat') !!}

{!! BootForm::text('captcha') !!}

{!! BootForm::submit('Send') !!}
{!! BootForm::close() !!}
```

The problem is that Laravel somehow determines that that is an Ajax request and set an JSON of errors (if they're present) to Response instead of retrieving HTML code of form plus errors messages for each input individually. The question is: how do I force it to render the view with errors like if it weren't through Ajax?

**UPDATE:** this is what I want to get (the form itself and errors if they're present):
 [image]

For @OuailB:

[image]

I've just noticed that when I do a normal POST request, it redirects me to the same page through a GET request so it seems like the error messages actually appear in the GET's body, not POST's so maybe there is no way. I'll think about it, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can create validator manually, and if it fails return what you want:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'username' => 'required|string|regex:/^[a-zA-Z\d]+$/',
    'email' => 'required|string|email',
    'homepage' => 'nullable|string|url',
    'text' => 'string',
    'captcha' => 'required|captcha',
    ],
    [
        'captcha.captcha' => 'The captcha is incorrect',
        'username.regex' => 'Use English letters and digits only',
    ]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return Redirect::back()
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput($request->all());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public function postMessageAjax(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'username' => 'required|string|regex:/^[a-zA-Z\d]+$/',
        'email' => 'required|string|email',
        'homepage' => 'nullable|string|url',
        'text' => 'string',
        'captcha' => 'required|captcha',
        ],
        [
            'captcha.captcha' => 'The captcha is incorrect',
            'username.regex' => 'Use English letters and digits only',
        ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return view('Guestbook.postMessage')
            ->withErrors($validator);
    }

    // Store your message here
}
```

**Edit :**
For displaying the errors, you can add this code into your view :

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: I get the form, but there's no errors in it although there should be.

Comment: You must add some code to display the errors, i`ve edited my post

Comment: So there is no way to make how it is in the picture?

Comment: I just seen that BootForm already has this feature, it should work as expected. Can you show the rendered view ?